# ZF2 An alias "translator" was requested but no service could be found. error on creating new skeleton project

Tags: zend-framework2

I just downloaded the ZendFrameworkSkeleton for ZF2 from github. Everything is in order, but I am getting this error:

`An alias "translator" was requested but no service could be found.`

I know nothing about ZF2. Can someone assist?

Heres where I got it: [ZF2Skeleton](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication)

EDIT***

I found this code in `module/Application/config/module.config.php`:

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'abstract_factories' => array(
        'Zend\Cache\Service\StorageCacheAbstractServiceFactory',
        'Zend\Log\LoggerAbstractServiceFactory',
    ),
    'aliases' => array(
        'translator' => 'MvcTranslator',
    ),
),
'translator' => array(
    'locale' => 'en_US',
    'translation_file_patterns' => array(
        array(
            'type'     => 'gettext',
            'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
            'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
        ),
    ),
),
```

Comment: Try doing a `composer update` first. There was an issue with conflicting service names which has been fixed a few days ago.

Comment: can you post that as an answer so i can approve it as the correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing a `composer update` first. There was an issue with conflicting service names which has been fixed a few days ago.

Comment: I had the same issue deploying the skeleton application in Zen Studio 10 (with composer support). The dependencies did not update automatically so I dropped into the shell and did a `composer update`.